# How to make linear layouts scrollable inside an coordinator layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't want to use recycler view here.
Because here is 3-4 Linear Layouts with static data.

I am using coordinator layout here, how can I make scrollable linear layouts inside it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".EarnActivity">
    
        <include layout="@layout/appbar"></include>



<- Here I want to insert linear layouts,
     But how can I make this coordinator layout scrollable. 
          All things inside it should Scroll -->
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNav3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/item_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/item_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">
    
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Add them into a nestedscrollview

Comment: To improve Priyanka's comment , you need to wrap these layouts inside a linear or relative layout, then wrap it with nested scroll view. A nested scroll view can only have 1 child, otherwise your app will crash.

Comment: And add them layout behaviour as scrollable